# I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 but now I am not getting multi boot option

Tags: dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu and chose the option which says install Ubuntu alongside Windows, however now when I restarted my PC directly Ubuntu opens and I cannot use Windows now. Please help!

Comment: If you are booting Ubuntu, you do not need to install grub again in some boot mode. But did you install Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM boot mode and Windows is in UEFI boot mode? Can you go into UEFI/BIOS and directly boot Windows? Or one time boot key like f10 or f12? Boot-Repair can convert a BIOS install to UEFI with advanced settings. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair But do not reinstall Ubuntu unless you use the Something Else install option or you will erase Windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu, it also installs GRUB. GRUB is pretty much a boot-loader you will use to boot Windows. All you have to do is hold **Shift** while your PC is booting up which will bring up a menu. It should show *Ubuntu* and *Windows.*

Use the **arrow keys** to navigate to Windows and press **Enter**. Windows should now boot up.

If this doesn't work then GRUB may have not installed with Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, type in this down in *Terminal*.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Once that is done, redo the steps. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also install grub- customizer and edit the boot options using a GUI if you dont want too much command line stuff;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then, launch it from the dash or the command line, either is fine. It will ask you for a password, and then open. Here you can change things such as boot order, the time to wait before booting the default OS, and a bunch of other stuff.